# update pipe separated Numeric Id with AlphaIds

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a requirment where I need to replace these pipe delimited Numeric employee Ids with Alphanumeric Employee Ids based on join with a master table on Numeric EmployeeIds

1384820|1379944|1376152|1252113|1250813|1246172|1084122|1037839

as

```
UPDATE Search..SF_PER
SET UserId = EU.AlpId
FROM ExtranetUsers EU WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Search..SF_PER PT 
ON EU.EmpId = PT.UserId
```

Also the number pipe separated empids may vary. I want to update whole table for this and I am trying to avoid loops.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just one of many reasons why storing *multiple* data items in a single row/column is a **bad** idea. SQL *has* a datatype designed for storing multiple items - it's called a table. If you design your schema properly, using multiple rows to store multiple data items, most queries become substantially easier to write.

Comment: i did not design my scema and its very old. I am just supposed to work with it. Please suggest of any solutions if u have.